# CIFilter equivalents for CGContext .normal and .color blend modes

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, cifilter

I've been trying to replicate the SKSpriteNode colorizing method using CIFilter in order to use it on another type of SKNode such as SKEffectNode.
[This reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skspritenode?language=objc) under **Colorizing a Sprite Node** provides a way to simply colorize sprites. How can I do the same with any SKEffectSprite.

I've recreated an emulation for this colorization in CoreGraphics adding a `tinted` function (see below) to UIImage. It works okay and gives similar results. The only issue is that CIImage and CGImage are not playing nice on many versions of iOS (buggy!).

I am now turning to setting a standard CIFilter using compositing filters without being successful at it.

[This page](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html) provides multiple options but it seems very difficult to match what I am doing in CoreGraphics with any particular filter in CoreImage and without knowing the formulas. Is there a way to get a CIFilter existing composite filter chain to get similar results as the colorization algorithm in SKSpriteNode?

```
extension UIImage {

    public func tinted(color: UIColor, colorBlendFactor: CGFloat) -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, scale)
        defer { UIGraphicsEndImageContext() }

        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return self }

        context.translateBy(x: 0, y: size.height)
        context.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)
        let rect = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: size.width, height: size.height)

        context.setBlendMode(.normal)
        UIColor.black.setFill()
        context.fill(rect)
        context.setBlendMode(.normal)

        let cgImage = self.cgImage
        context.draw(cgImage!, in: rect)

        context.setBlendMode(.color)
        color.withAlphaComponent(colorBlendFactor).setFill()
        context.fill(rect)

        context.setBlendMode(.destinationIn)
        context.draw(cgImage!, in: rect)

        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        return image!
    }
}
```

Comment: if you are doing this in sprite kit, then you do not want to be using CGContext.  You want to be using shaders. I am not sure if i am following your problem here, but why don't you just place a sprite node as a child of the effect node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure out how to build a CIFilter for tinting images the way SKSpriteNode blends color. From the picture below, the left hand side is Apple's blend algorithm. On the right hand side, my CIFilter algorithm:

[image]

Here is the code below written in Swift4:

```
import CoreImage
import UIKit

class TintFilter: CIFilter {

    @objc dynamic var inputImage: CIImage?

    var color = UIColor.black
    var colorBlendFactor: CGFloat = 1.0

    public init(color: UIColor, colorBlendFactor: CGFloat) {
        super.init()
        self.color = color
        self.colorBlendFactor = colorBlendFactor
    }

    required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    private func computeBlendComponent(_ component: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        return 1.0 - (colorBlendFactor * (1.0 - component))
    }

    override open var outputImage: CIImage? {

        guard let inputImage = self.inputImage else {
            return nil
        }

        let colorGenerator = CIFilter(name:"CIConstantColorGenerator")

        var hue: CGFloat = 0.0, saturation: CGFloat = 0.0, brightness: CGFloat = 0.0, alpha: CGFloat = 0.0
        color.getHue(&hue, saturation: &saturation, brightness:&brightness, alpha:&alpha)
        brightness += colorBlendFactor - 1.0
        brightness = max(min(brightness, 1.0), 0.0)
        let newColor = UIColor(hue: hue, saturation: saturation, brightness:brightness, alpha:alpha)

        let inputColor = CIColor(cgColor: newColor.cgColor)
        colorGenerator?.setValue(inputColor, forKey: "inputColor")

        guard var colorOutputImage = colorGenerator?.outputImage else {
            return nil
        }

        colorOutputImage = CIImage(color: CIColor(color: self.color.withAlphaComponent(self.colorBlendFactor)))

        return colorOutputImage.applyingFilter("CIMultiplyCompositing", parameters: ["inputBackgroundImage": inputImage]).applyingFilter("CIMultiplyBlendMode", parameters: ["inputBackgroundImage": inputImage])
    }
}
```